# SwingWorker and command line process interrupts

Tags: java, swing, command-line, concurrency, swingworker

I am trying to build a Swing solution for compressing files which is relayed on the rar command line. As the GUI needs to stay responsive I've wrapped the code for dealing with the command line into a SwingWorker class.

```
SwingWorker<Boolean, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Boolean, String>(){
        protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {

            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

            try {
                //daj processu da ode u background nekako, da ga ne sjebem sa ctrl + c (winrar umesto rar)
                String command = "my command, this works just fine";

                Process p = rt.exec(command, null, new File("C:\\Program Files\\WinRar"));


                BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                         InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String s = null;
                System.out.println("<INPUT>");
                while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
                System.out.println("</INPUT>");
                InputStream stderr = p.getErrorStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                System.out.println("<ERROR>");
                String line = null;
                while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(line);
                    return false;

                }
                System.out.println("</ERROR>");
                int exitVal = p.waitFor();
                //EXIT VALUE IS ALWAYS 0, EVEN IF I INTERRUPT IT WITH CTRL+C
                System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);



            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //SOME GUI UPDATES
        }
        @Override
        protected void done() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Boolean status = false;
            try {
                status = get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //MORE GUI UPDATES
            if(status){
                tableList.setValueAt("Done", row, 3);
            } else{
                tableList.setValueAt("Error", row, 3);
            } 
            super.done();
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
```

When I delete printing of input and error, exit value is printed as soon as rar appears on the screen. So there is no actual point of "waitFor()" method in my code. What I need is to check if rar closed without interrupts  (like CTRL + C, or hitting "X" on cmd window) and get the exit code. I've tried adding shutdown hook on runtime (rt variable) but it reacts when I close the whole GUI.

Comment: And side note: the fact that you have one SwingWorker doesn't mean that you have push all your code into a single method. You might want to read about the "single layer of abstraction principle".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get your input and error streams, and read from them each in its own thread. Right now your error stream never has a chance because of the blocking while loop ahead of it.

I've used the following code (although it is years old...):

Enum: GobblerType.java

```
enum GobblerType {
   ERROR, OUTPUT
}
```

Class StreamGobbler.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class StreamGobbler implements Runnable {

   private InputStream is;
   private GobblerType type;
   private OutputStream os;

   public StreamGobbler(InputStream is, GobblerType type) {
      this(is, type, null);
   }

   public StreamGobbler(InputStream is, GobblerType type, OutputStream redirect) {
      this.is = is;
      this.type = type;
      this.os = redirect;
   }

   public void run() {
      try {
         PrintWriter pw = null;
         if (os != null) {
            pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
         }
         InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
         String line = null;
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (pw != null) {
               pw.println(line);
            }
         }
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

And then have used it like so:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(.....);  // TODO: Fix!

StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(), GobblerType.ERROR);
StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(), GobblerType.OUTPUT);

new Thread(errorGobbler).start();
new Thread(outputGobbler).start();

int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
proc.destroy();
```

---

---

OK, I created some code as a proof of concept program. I've modified my Gobbler a bit so that it doesn't require an OutputStream but rather uses a PropertyChangeListener to notify listeners of any text coming from the InputStream. For this to work, all my code is in the same package, and note that package names are key, and you would likely need to change yours. Running this code does behave as expected. It is a bit overly simplistic and probably should use some type of blocking queue for passing information between classes.

---

### GobblerType.java

An enum to distinguish the two type of stream gobblers in use

```
package pkg2;

public enum GobblerType {
    ERROR, OUTPUT
}
```

---

### StreamGobbler2.java

The stream gobbler that uses an input stream reader to get text from the input stream, puts the text into a `text` field, and notifies listeners of new text. It uses a PropertyChangeListener for the notification. This is a crude way to producer-consumer, and risks not capturing all passed information. Better would be to use a blocking queue of some sort.

```
package pkg2;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class StreamGobbler2 implements Callable<Void> {
    private PropertyChangeSupport support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private InputStream is;
    private GobblerType type;
    private String text;

    public StreamGobbler2(InputStream is, GobblerType type) {
        this.is = is;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            setText(line);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public GobblerType getType() {
        return type;
    }
    
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        support.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        support.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }
    
    public void setText(String text) {
        String oldValue = null;
        String newValue = text;
        this.text = text;
        support.firePropertyChange(type.toString(), oldValue, newValue);
    }
    
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

}
```

---

### ProcessLauncher.java

This is a non-Swing class that captures the information from the two gobblers. Again, better would be to use blocking queues (next iteration)

```
package pkg2;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class ProcessLauncher implements Callable<Integer> {
    private ExecutorService execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    private List<String> commands;
    private List<PropertyChangeListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public ProcessLauncher(List<String> commands) {
        this.commands = commands;
    }
    
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        Process p = pb.start();
        int exitValue = 0;

        try (InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
             InputStream errorStream = p.getErrorStream()) {

            StreamGobbler2 errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler2(inputStream, GobblerType.OUTPUT);
            StreamGobbler2 outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler2(errorStream, GobblerType.ERROR);
            
            for (PropertyChangeListener listener : listeners) {
                errorGobbler.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
                outputGobbler.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);                
            }

            List<Future<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
            futures.add(execService.submit(errorGobbler));
            futures.add(execService.submit(outputGobbler));
            execService.shutdown();

            exitValue = p.waitFor();
            for (Future<Void> future : futures) {
                future.get();
            }
        }

        return exitValue;
    }
}
```

---

### SwingWorkerWrapper.java

Wrapper to use the above class in a Swing fashion

```
package pkg2;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class SwingWorkerWrapper extends SwingWorker<Integer, Void> {
    private ProcessLauncher processLauncher;
    
    public SwingWorkerWrapper(List<String> commands) {
        processLauncher = new ProcessLauncher(commands);
        processLauncher.addPropertyChangeListener(new LauncherListener());
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {        
        return processLauncher.call();
    }
    
    private class LauncherListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            firePropertyChange(evt.getPropertyName(), evt.getOldValue(), evt.getNewValue());
        }
    }
}
```

---

### MainGui.java

GUI class that uses the above SwingWorker. Run this class to get the whole show on the road. Once running, press the "Launch Process" button for this program to run the TestProgram in a separate JVM.

```
package pkg2;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainGui extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] CMD_TEXT = {"java", "-cp"}; 
    private static final String TEST_PROGRAM = "pkg2.TestProgram";
    private JTextArea inputTextArea = new JTextArea(15, 30);
    private JTextArea errorTextArea = new JTextArea(15, 30);
    private List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public MainGui() {
        for (String cmd : CMD_TEXT) {
            commands.add(cmd);
        }
        String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        commands.add(classpath);
        commands.add(TEST_PROGRAM);
        
        inputTextArea.setFocusable(false);
        JScrollPane inputScrollPane = new JScrollPane(inputTextArea);
        inputScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        Border outsideBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Input Messages");
        Border border = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outsideBorder, inputScrollPane.getBorder());
        inputScrollPane.setBorder(border);
        
        errorTextArea.setFocusable(false);
        JScrollPane errorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(errorTextArea);
        errorScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        outsideBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Error Messages");
        border = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outsideBorder, errorScrollPane.getBorder());
        errorScrollPane.setBorder(border);
        
        JPanel twoAreasPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 3, 3));
        twoAreasPanel.add(inputScrollPane);
        twoAreasPanel.add(errorScrollPane);
        
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 3, 3));
        btnPanel.add(new JButton(new LaunchProcessAction()));
        btnPanel.add(new JButton(new ExitAction()));
        
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
        add(twoAreasPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);        
    }
    
    private class SwWrapperListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                SwingWorkerWrapper swW = (SwingWorkerWrapper) evt.getSource();
                try {
                    int exitCode = swW.get();
                    inputTextArea.append("Exit Code: " + exitCode + "\n");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    inputTextArea.append(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    inputTextArea.append("\n");
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    inputTextArea.append(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    inputTextArea.append("\n");
                }
            } else if (GobblerType.OUTPUT.toString().equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                inputTextArea.append(evt.getNewValue() + "\n");
            } else if (GobblerType.ERROR.toString().equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                errorTextArea.append(evt.getNewValue() + "\n");
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    private class LaunchProcessAction extends MyAction {
        public LaunchProcessAction() {
            super("Launch Process", KeyEvent.VK_L);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            SwingWorkerWrapper swWrapper = new SwingWorkerWrapper(commands);
            swWrapper.addPropertyChangeListener(new SwWrapperListener());
            swWrapper.execute();
        }
    }
    
    private class ExitAction extends MyAction {
        public ExitAction() {
            super("Exit", KeyEvent.VK_X);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    private static abstract class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
        public MyAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MainGui mainPanel = new MainGui();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

---

### TestProgram.java

Don't run this program directly, but rather have the Main GUI run this. Be sure that this code and all the code is compiled however

```
package pkg2;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestProgram extends JPanel {
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
    private JSpinner exitCodeSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, -10, 10, 1));
    
    public TestProgram() {        
        SendTextAction sendTextAxn = new SendTextAction();
        textField.setAction(sendTextAxn);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.add(textField);
        panel1.add(new JButton(sendTextAxn));

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.add(new JLabel("Exit Code:"));
        panel2.add(exitCodeSpinner);
        panel2.add(new JButton(new ExitCodeAction()));
        panel2.add(new JButton(new ThrowExceptionAction()));
        
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        add(panel1);
        add(panel2);
    }

    private static abstract class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
        public MyAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

    }
    
    private class SendTextAction extends MyAction {
        public SendTextAction() {
            super("Send Text", KeyEvent.VK_S);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = textField.getText();
            textField.setText("");
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }
    
    private class ExitCodeAction extends MyAction {
        public ExitCodeAction() {
            super("Exit Code", KeyEvent.VK_X);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int exitCode = (int) exitCodeSpinner.getValue();
            System.exit(exitCode);
        }
    }
    
    private class ThrowExceptionAction extends MyAction {
        public ThrowExceptionAction() {
            super("Throw Exception", KeyEvent.VK_T);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // throw some unchecked exception
            throw new NumberFormatException("Unchecked exception thrown from within TestProgram");
        }
    }
    
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TestProgram mainPanel = new TestProgram();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Program");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing gets printed, I've just tried your code, but also I tried something similar and also nothing gets printed. Could it be something involving SwingWorker, because it works in separate thread as I understood?